# JUnit assertEqual for doubles with percentage delta

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In JUnit, the assertEquals for doubles takes a delta that is absolute. But isn't a percentage value more appropriate for margin than an absolute value? When one is comparing two large values, it is likely that the error due to rounding up, if any, will result in the last significant digit irrespective of the exponent. Having an absolute delta doesn't help in such cases, does it?

It's not difficult and I wrote one, but just curious why JUnit doesn't have that function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the situation.  If you have a fixed precision e.g. two decimal places you might want a delta of 0.5e-2, but if you have an unknown precision and you want significant digits you may need something more complicated like

```
assertEquals(expected, actual, Math.abs(expected) / 1e3);
```

The problem with relative error is it is harder to know if it should be relative to the expected, the actual or some combination of the two.

Comment: Just a nitpick - I think it's pretty logical that relative would be to the expected. I can't think of a logical case where one would have margin specified in terms of actual.

Comment: @LakshmanKakkirala I am quite used to actual and so I use it naturally if you want two numbers to be the same to within 0.005 as you have two decimal places of precision, this is a normal use case.  If you use double, you always need to use sensible rounding and relative errors are not as meaningful if you do this.

Comment: Won't your value of what's correct and incorrect vary with the actual?
I know it may not matter much, but in theory, the two are not the same, and I'm still not sure where you'd define the success or failure of a test not on the expected value but on the actual value! Can you give an example, may be?

Answer (score 0):

One can only assume as there is no clue in the JUnit API, but it targets small differences in number representations in the floating point domain (when you got a difference in the 15th position after decimal point). After all, it is by far easier to come from the absolute value version to the procentual version **than the other way around**.

Answer (score 0):

A percentage tolerance would be no good for the case that the expected value was zero, but you were willing to accept a very small value as good enough. The cuurent API is therefore useable to all numeric values.

Comment: Agreed. And like others have said, a percentage error can be simulated. But it would have been better to have it directly as part of the API so that user mistakes are minimized.